# Make field email validate and required

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator, requiredfieldvalidator

I need to have a textbox be validated as an email address, and make it a required field. I also need to restrict the email addresses to a specific domain name only (e.g. @example.com).

```
<asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>' 
                                    MaxLength="50" />
```

What is the best approach to this?

Answer (score 2):

It would work better if you add

```
ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
```

instead of

```
ValidationExpression="^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@domain.com$"
```

in the code above

Comment: He had said he had a requirement of a specific domain. This does not validate that requirement.